# Ubuntu 20.04 apt update && apt upgrade - DELL XPS 13 9310 no longer boots to Ubuntu

Tags: boot, 20.04, dell, xps

### "Ubuntu 20.04 apt update && apt upgrade - DELL XPS 13 9310 no longer boots to Ubuntu"

--
Yesterday my Dell XPS 13 9310 Developer Edition laptop with 20.04 Ubuntu worked fine.  Logged in, etc. Worked great.  Then...

I ran my normal command (via bash alias)
'sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade'

--- I noticed it complained about a missing firmware file,
but it continued and and completed.

-- TODAY My XPS 13 9310 Ubuntu laptop no longer boots.  I get to the Dell-in-Circle with the caps lock hit on, then at 7 seconds, light on caps lock goes off, and then at 8 seconds Dell-in-Circle disappears leaving me with a blank (black screen).

All I did was do the "sudo apt update -y && sudo apt upgrade -y" on a previously running Ubuntu 20.04 Developer edition laptop working since March.

Here's excerpt (retyped from screenshot via phone)

```
Processing triggers ...
Processing triggers plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text (0.9.4....) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activitate)
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.16-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up gnome-settings-daemon (3.36.1-0ubuntu1.1)
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.10.0-1044-oem (5.10 ...) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5-10.0-1044-OEM
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_huc_7.5.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_huc_7.5.0.bin for module i915
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file '/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file '/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Sourcing file '/etc/default/grub.d/oem-flavour.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-1044.oem
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.10.1044.oem
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-1038.oem
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.10.1038.oem
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-1034.oem
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.10.1034.oem
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools: (0.136ubuntu6.6) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5-10.0-1044-OEM
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_huc_7.5.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_huc_7.5.0.bin for module i915
me@xps9310:~$
```

So I got prompt.   Later I shutdown system after review some videos.

Today I turn it on and nothing but the Dell-in-Circle.

Ideas? Can't get to "F12 Boot Menu" (that string displays in upper right along with Dell-in-Circle but never goes to string

I added a usb-c to HDMI cable and tried to see if screen issue but no luck.

LAST NOTE:  In Spring, I did apply a firmware update from https://fwupd.org/lvfs/devices/com.dell.ueficfb08d7c.firmware -- so I was surprised to see the firmware upgrade take place with Ubuntu upgrade.

I just don't want to miss any simple workaround before I use my Dell Pro plus warranty.

Thanks in advance,
Tim

Comment: Working with Dell Support.   I will list the XPS key sequences they had be walk through after I get off call. Might be helpful to get to Support tool, OS recovery tool, Grub settings (when Drive is okay), etc.

Comment: Is this the Ubuntu that came preinstalled on your machine? Indeed, nowadays, bios and firmware upgrades are done through Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi @vanadium - thanks for reply.  Well the good news is that Dell honored the ProPlus NBD KYHD support I had. They tried replacing the motherboard twice (it has 1165 chipset), and finally since they had no refurbished units with native install Ubuntu, they manufactured a new one.  They replaced the system identically -- except swap the 1165 with the 1185.
Since brand new replacement arrived, I have always been able to (use the keyboard sequences to update unit; use firmware update without issue, etc..
LEMON?  I don't know.  However I do appreciate having a native Linux laptop once again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue a month or so back. Eventually I was able to boot to a terminal and the following fixed it for me:

`fwupdmgr refresh --force && fwupdmgr upgrade`

I did have to use a USB C adapter to plug into ethernet since my WiFi wasn't working.

Comment: Thanks for the summary.   

I do want to know that Ubuntu wasn't happy when I ran commands to permanently disable bluetooth (in my bash script at startup).